# JSP hypertext link to index page

Tags: java, jsp

can You explain me how to make hypertext links between .jsp files?
I found two possible options, the firs is: `<a href="index.jsp">index</a>` but there is a problem that my url now contains ".jsp" string at the end (and we dont want that).
Second possibility is this:

```
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>">index</a>
```

this is working great, but question is this is a good practise because there can be a lot of links in my web application and to have scriptlet in every anchor is not very nice to see. How do you solve links between jsp files? thanks

EDIT:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=6ynkpl&s=8#.VC8NjBaimS4
-here is my problem, as you can see in the picture, index.jsp and register.jsp are not in the same folder level. (other jsp files are just parts of both index and register), and I have many links just in navigation.jsp, so from there, I cannot determine to what level should I call my .jsp file in  tag. Clear now?

example: clicking link on navigation from index requires `<a href="index.jsp">index</a>` while clicking that link when I'm in register jsp requires `<a href="../../index.jsp">index</a>` //if I'm not wrong, I didn't try it, it's just for imagination.

Comment: Are you importing a jsp page or are you trying to just have a link to another page that will be displayed on the link being clicked?

Comment: The question is confused. Are you asking how remove the .jsp extension from the url or how to make a relative link?

Comment: second one, (nothing wrong, but have you read my question and my examples?). I'm just tring to have a link to another page - as I showed with the <a> tags and wrote down.

Comment: @developerwjk relative links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using what is called the core jstl libraries to do what you're looking for.

Especially look at the [url tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm).

Example:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/" />">Index</a>
<a href="<c:url value="/user/register.html" />">Register</a>
```

Comment: I still need to know in what directory I'm.

Comment: I've updated my answer, a bit.  You can use the url tag and it is always based from the base context of your application.  So you do not need to know which directory you're in, just where you need to go from the base context of your application.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, my mistake, I didn't add jstl core library :/ solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same level:

```
<a href="./index.jsp">index</a>
```

One level back:

```
<a href="../index.jsp">index</a>
```

Two levels back:

```
<a href="../../index.jsp">index</a>
```

If you want to get rid of the `.jsp` you can either map your jsp to a different URL in web.xml (kind of a pain), or install [Tuckey URL Rewrite filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) (more versatile, since it uses regex). I'd suggest the Tuckey option since it will let you turn URL path info into parameters.

Like for instance `http://localhost/app/index/1/2/3/` could be mapped to run on the back-end as `http://localhost/app/index.jsp?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3`

Comment: OK...I wrote that if i put name of jsp with ".jsp" at the end then it will be shown in the URL and I don't want that. Second thing, for example I have only one header in my page, which is included into all of my .jsp's. So I can click the link from every .jsp, result= how will I detect from what level Am I clicking?? my jsp files are in folders and subfolders..

Comment: That's why I asked you if you want to remove the .jsp extension from the url or how to make a relative link. I guess you want both, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Pink, Its not automatic. You have to read the docs and setup the config file. There's no automatic way to translate `index` to `index.jsp` without modifying some xml files etc.

Comment: @Pink, You know which level each file is at when you write the code.

Comment: yes but the problem is that the <a> tag is not in index.jsp or register.jsp, but it's in navigation.jsp (because of I don't want to have menu items in every .jsp file)

Comment: @Pink, Then you can use the full path like `/app/dir/dir/dir/file.jsp` in all the links. `./` means current directory, while `/` (no dot) means the webroot.

Comment: Yes, that's I was asking for in my topic question, but I was using this instead: <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()/dir/dir/file.jsp %>">index</a> - that's equal like your idea, but I was asking if there is easier way because i can have a lot of <a> tags and i dont want to have so many scriptlets. Another way I would like to have all my links at same concept

Comment: I do not like relative URL in web applications, because it is likely to break at first refactoring ... but you are on your own ;-)